# Cannot attach letsencrypt to dokku

Tags: dokku, lets-encrypt

I get the following error when running dokku letsencrypt myapp. I'm on Dokku 0.7.0

```
root@resend:~# dokku letsencrypt production
=====> Let's Encrypt production...
-----> Updating letsencrypt docker image...
latest: Pulling from dokkupaas/letsencrypt-simp_le
420890c9e918: Already exists 
e4a2ae244258: Already exists 
5c6ac6d1c950: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:18a19b34beceba79dd5be458abe7e132fc7486da1da19cc4d0395ad4578031ef
Status: Image is up to date for dokkupaas/letsencrypt-simp_le:latest
       done
-----> Enabling ACME proxy for production...
-----> Getting letsencrypt certificate for production...
        - Domain 'production.resend.io'
        - Domain 'resend.io'
        - Domain 'ws.resend.io'
        - Domain 'www.resend.io'
darkhttpd/1.11, copyright (c) 2003-2015 Emil Mikulic.
listening on: http://0.0.0.0:80/
2016-08-01 22:34:32,324:INFO:__main__:1211: Generating new account key
2016-08-01 22:34:38,247:INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:758: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org
2016-08-01 22:34:38,593:INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:758: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org
2016-08-01 22:34:38,754:INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:758: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org
2016-08-01 22:34:39,294:INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:758: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): letsencrypt.org
TOS hash mismatch. Found: 6373439b9f29d67a5cd4d18cbc7f264809342dbf21cb2ba2fc7588df987a6221.

Debugging tips: -v improves output verbosity. Help is available under --help.
-----> Certificate retrieval failed!
-----> Disabling ACME proxy for production...
       done
```

Comment: This is also a problem on version 0.6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is temporary while some dependencies update. There is a workaround documented here:

https://github.com/dokku/dokku-letsencrypt/issues/73

Answer (score 0):

For me i just update the letsencrypt plugin on dokku by launching

```
dokku plugin:update letsencrypt master
```

After relaunch `dokku letsencrypt:auto-renew`